# A question about the quotient topology in normed linear spaces.

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

Say $M$ is a closed linear subspace of normed linear space $N$. The coset of the form $x+M, x\in N$ in the quotient space $N/M$ is defined by $$\|x+M\|=\inf\{\|x+m\|:m\in M\}$$

Let us consider the case $\|x+M\|=0$. The book "Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis" by Simmons says that $x\in M$. **I don't understand why that is.** Shouldn't the norm have been $$\|x+M\|=\inf\{\|x-m\|:m\in M\}$$ for that to be true? $\|x+m\|$ is just equivalent to adding the vectors $x$ and $m$ and finding the modulus of the sum.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $m$ and $-m$ are both in $M$ since it is a vector space.

Comment: Oh. OK. I thought the wording "closed linear subspace" implied any closed subset of $N$. Does "closed" here mean closed under addition, or a closed set?

Comment: Closed with respect to the norm, so closed set. The word "subspace" indicates closure under addition (amongst including 0 and closure under scalar multiplication). $M$ needs to be closed for $\|x+M\|=0$ to imply that $x\in M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\|x+M\|=0$, then $\inf_{m \in M} \|x+m\| = 0$. Hence there is a sequence $m_k \in M$ such that $\|x+m_k\| \to 0$, or in other words, $x+m_k \to 0$, which can be written as $(-m_k) \to x$. Since $M$ is closed, it follows that $x \in M$.

Similarly, if $x \in M$ (remember $M$ is a subspace), then we have $0 \le \inf_{m \in M} \|x+m\| \le \|x+(-x)\| = 0$, and so $\|x+M\| = 0$.